# CP-divisible in Markovian and non-Markovian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, open-quantum-systems

There is a definition that says if the decay rates are positive the dynamical map would be CP- divisible semi-group and Markovian. On the other hand, the non-Markovian occurs when at least one of the decay rates is negative for a certain interval time.

Can anyone tell me how to find proof of the concept to have a deeper understanding of it?
How does the decay rate affect the difference?

[image: it is a part from the paper "IBM Q Experience as a versatile experimental testbed for simulating open quantum systems"]

$$\dot{\rho}_s(t) = \mathcal{L}_t\rho_s(t)$$

$$\Phi_t = T\exp\bigg(\int_0^t\mathcal{L} d\tau\bigg)$$

$$\mathcal{L}_t\rho_s(t) = -i[H_s,\rho_s (t)]+\sum_k  \gamma_k (t)\big(V_k \rho_s (t) V_k^\dagger-\frac{1}{2}\{V_k^\dagger V_k ,\rho_s(t)\}\big)$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your consideration. I have added more details from the exact source.

Comment: it is a part of the paper "IBM Q Experience as a versatile experimental testbed
for simulating open quantum systems"

Comment: The question is not very clear IMO. Which part do you want proof? That if you have negative decay rates your map is negative?

Comment: yes exactly. honestly, I am new to open quantum systems and I do not know completely it deeply.